# How can I remove everything except listed files with the Find-command?

Tags: list, shell, find

I have a list of hidden files in a file "list_files" that should not be removed in the current directory. How can remove everything except them with a Find-command? I tried, but it clearly does not work:

```
find . -iname ".*" \! -iname 'list_files'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing files should always be done safely.

I presume you have a directory tree with hidden files and a sub-set list of these hidden files which you want to retain. You want to delete all other hidden files.

Lets start with the list of hidden files.

```
find `pwd` -iname ".*" -type f > all-hidden-files.txt
```

Now, assume that you have some filter which will reduce the list to all files that you want to retain (creating your list_files). Here **SomeFilter** could be you manually editing the files list to retain the ones you do not want to delete.

```
SomeFilter all-hidden-files.txt > list_files
```

The next command will identify lines in all-hidden-files.txt that are missing from the list_files, which gives you files that can be removed.

```
comm -3 all-hidden-files.txt list_files > removable-files.txt
```

Edit: Just realized that the input files to comm should be sorted. So use this as,

```
comm -3 <(sort all-hidden-files.txt | uniq) <(sort list_files | uniq) \
    > removable-files.txt
```

You can confirm this works well for you and then delete the list of files generated with something like,

```
for i in $(<removable-files.txt); do rm $i; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by invoking exec with a bash script so something like this :-

```
find . -iname ".*" -exec bash -c "fgrep {} /tmp/list_files >/dev/null || rm -i {}" \;
```

Be very careful how your construct your list of files. The list of files to exclude must be identical to the output produced by find or you will delete all files matching your pattern.

I have put the interactive option on to rm and you may wish to use this for testing. If you wish to remove directories with this technique then you will need to modify the rm options.

You may wish to construct your list of files using find from the same folder you will use to run the find to ensure the exclusions will be honoured although an absolute rather than a relative path would be a better i.e. safer option, so your find would become

```
find /some/folder/name -name "some pattern" -exec ....
```

Answer (score 1):

create a temporary directory in your source directory, move everything to the temp directory, move the files you want to save back up to the original place, and then recursively remove the temp directory.  Since the moves are all on one filesystem, it should be almost instantaneous with any decent filesystem, and this is pretty safe.